# devtools::build: "Error in if (!is_loaded(pkg) || (is_loaded(pkg) && reload)) { : missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed"

Tags: r, devtools, r-package

Everytime I try use the devtools functions build, check or document a certain R-package folder it throws the following error:

Error in if (!is_loaded(pkg) || (is_loaded(pkg) && reload)) { : 
  missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed

or if (pkgname != intname)... , respectively, for build.

It has worked for that particular package before I added some additional code, but removing it doesn't seem to help. What does this error mean and what to look for to find a solution?

Comment: Starting all over again with a new package with exactly the same contents seems to have solved the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would mean that you have a hidden character that you are not seeing attached to the name of the package (It happened to me yesterday after editing the description file using the notepad). So, try to find what it is and erase it. And (note to self) do not edit the R files with the notepad again! :-) open them just with RStudio, Sublime text, etc.